# Wifi RSSI not updating when screen is turned off

Tags: android, sleep, android-wifi, wifimanager, rssi

I'm trying to get the current **RSSI** of a wifi connection in a **Service** using an **AsyncTask**. When the screen is turned off the value will not be updated until I turn the display back on again. So the value stays the same as the last value that was obtained before the display was turned off.

I used an Nexus 6P with Android O preview and a LG 3 with Android 6.

I'm obtaining a **WakeLock** and a **WifiLock** before via:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "WifiMeasureTaskWakeLock");
mWakeLock.acquire();

mWifiLock = mWifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "WifiMeasureTaskWifiLock");
mWifiLock.acquire();
```

And in the doInBackground method I'm doing the following:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

    int dBm;

    try {
       //some other code here

        while (true) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                //some other code here
                return null;
            }

            try {
                //some other code here

                //does not update when the screen if turned off
                dBm = Math.max(mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(), -100);

                //some other code here
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               //some other code here
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        //some other code here
    }
    return null;
}
```

I already found an [issue in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36958342) but it's marked obsolete.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?